# JDK implementation of Thread.join()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm

I was wondering how Java implements the join() method to wait for a thread to finish. According to the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.join%28long%29):

```
public final synchronized void  [More ...] join(long millis)
throws InterruptedException {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = 0;

    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }

    } else {
        while (isAlive()) {
            long delay = millis - now;
            if (delay <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            wait(delay);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
        }
    }
}
```

The calling thread obtains the running thread's monitor and wait() at line 1160 indefinitely while running thread is still alive.

My question is: where is (and who calls) the notify() or notifyAll() when the thread completes, so that it wakes up the calling thread?

To be perfectly clear, the question is about **where in the JDK/JVM** is notify() called, not in our code.

Thank you.

Comment: It's part of the JDK's implementation of thread. When `run` returns, it does the equivalent of calling `notifyAll`.

Comment: it is called somewhere in native code (written in c++)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

notifyAll (or its native equivalent) is called in ensure_join in [src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp#l1526), at line 1526 in the current version, which is called from JavaThread::exit in the same file.