# Mechanism of join() in multithreading

Tags: multithreading

I was studying about multi-threading and came across `join()`.

As I understand right, using `join()` on the thread makes process wait until 'joined' thread terminates. For example, calling `t1.join()` in `main` will make `main` wait until the job in thread `t1` is finished and `t1` terminates.

I'm just curious that how the function `join()` make this possible - how does it make current thread 'blocked' inside the function? Does `join()` force execution of joined thread first so any other thread should wait until that thread terminates? Or, is there some way to communicate between two threads(the thread who called `join()` and the thread who is joined)?

I will be waiting for the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What language/instruction set?

Comment: I was just studying broad concept - let's say Python. Does the mechanism differ by programming language?

Comment: For Java, see http://www.stackoverflow.com/q/22495652/100836

Comment: Yes, it's language specific. There's a difference in how threads are implemented between languages and OS platforms. The language usually abstracts the platform specific element.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to join you need to be able to wait on some event. Then join looks like this:

```
function join(t : Thread)
    // do this atomically
    if already done
        return
    wait on termination event of t
end
```

Waiting can be done in one of two ways:

1. Looping and periodically checking if the event has happened (busy wait)
2. Letting the system reclaim the resources of the thread and be woken up on a system event, in that case waking the thread is managed by the scheduler of the OS

Answer (score 0):

It's rather language specific.

Once you `create` a thread, it starts running.

A `join` operation is when your main process stops and waits for the thread to exit and capture a return code. It will block until your thread completes - that's rather the point, as it allows for a synchronization to occur - everything in your program is at a 'known state'.

Related is the `detach` operation, which is effectively saying 'I don't care any more'.

Comment: Your explanations are misleading: join is not "when your main process stops and waits" (for a specific example see the implementation of Java linked by Zaki). Your idea of thread creation is implementation dependent.